# mongodb add aggregate command to find command

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

my mongodb find code:

```
db.mycollection.runCommand( "text", { search: "yardim", limit:5})
```

aggregate command:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate(
{$match:{"source" : {$exists:true}}},
{$group:{_id:"$source", "count": {$sum:1}}} 
);
```

How do I integrate "aggregate" code to "find" code

Comment: I don't believe that it possible. The only option I see is to store aggregation function result in separate collection and create text index there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the joys of MongoDB is that it plays well with your programming language!
So I would encourage you to remember and (re)consider your programming language as the primary tool for implementing solutions.
I gently suggest that you do the "obvious", gather the results of your db operation, and insert what you want.
This should be your first solution.
Hopefully it will perform well enough for you, as it is also the only solution at present
(well, mapReduce can merge, but it forces the shape of its results into the merger).
The $out operator for aggregation (available as of version 2.5.2) is not a solution for merging.
While it writes the results to the collection specified by the value, you cannot merge back into the same collection.
If the collection already exists, the old existing collection is replaced with the new results for the collection.

Here's an example that hopefully illustrates the ease of using your programming language to solve your issue.

aggregate-insert.js

```
db.mycollection.drop();
db.mycollection.ensureIndex({ quote: "text", source: "text" });
var docs = [
    {quote: "Glory is fleeting, but obscurity is forever.", source: "Napoleon Bonaparte"},
    {quote: "Political correctness is tyranny with manners.", source: "Charlton Heston"},
    {quote: "Not everything that can be counted counts, and not everything that counts can be counted.", source: "Albert Einstein"},
    {quote: "Only two things are infinite, the universe and human stupidity, and I'm not sure about the former.", source: "Albert Einstein"},
    {quote: "In theory, there is no difference between theory and practice. But in practice, there is.", source: "Yogi Berra"},
    {quote: "I find that the harder I work, the more luck I seem to have.", source: "Thomas Jefferson"},
    {quote: "Never interrupt your enemy when he is making a mistake.", source: "Napoleon Bonaparte"},
    {quote: "The significant problems we face cannot be solved at the same level of thinking we were at when we created them.", source: "Albert Einstein"},
];
db.mycollection.insert(docs);
var aggregation = db.mycollection.aggregate(
    {$match: {source: {$exists: true}}},
    {$group: {_id: "$source", count: {$sum: 1}}},
    {$project: {_id: 0, source: "$_id", count: "$count"}}
);
db.mycollection.insert(aggregation.toArray());
var text_search = db.mycollection.runCommand( "text", { search: "Thomas", limit:5});
printjson(text_search.results);
```

$ mongo aggregate-insert.js

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.5.4-pre-
connecting to: test
[
    {
        "score" : 0.75,
        "obj" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("528e3250ac6deb4e169c900e"),
            "quote" : "I find that the harder I work, the more luck I seem to have.",
            "source" : "Thomas Jefferson"
        }
    },
    {
        "score" : 0.75,
        "obj" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("528e32504294d7fa2eedec1d"),
            "count" : 1,
            "source" : "Thomas Jefferson"
        }
    }
]
```